# manipulate var in list comprehension python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to compare two strings which have the following property:

```
s1 = abc...q
s2 = absc...q
```

The second string has some extra characters than the first one, but contains all the characters of the first one in the same order. I want to get the positions of these *s* characters but not with simple loop because it's too slow, so I wanted to model it with list comprehension with something like this :

```
diffs = [pos_2 for (pos_s1, pos_s2) in zip(range(len(s1), range(len(s2)))) 
if s1[pos_1] is not s2[pos_2] 
*and then do this operation* pos_1 -= 1]
```

but it seems I can't do such operations in list comprehension. Any suggestions how to deal with that?

Comment: By "extra characters" are they not in `s1` at all or they just happen to be breaking up the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a list comprehension like this

```
s1 = "abc...q"
s2 = "absc...q"

[index for index, elm in enumerate(s2) if elm not in s1]
```

Comment: It would be a little faster if `s1 = set(s1)`